# How to assign value to angular $scope in my blade.php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade

I get values form laravel `View::make('----', $data)`. And I want to assign some values to the angular `$scope.var1 ...`, if it cannot assign to `$scope`. Can I assign it to a local javascript var, and use the var in angular app?

Comment: What you are trying to do is bad practice. What is the main goal you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format your inline code sample with backticks so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide additional details that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: @JaredEitnier. Thanks. I get your idea. I'll change from server side render to client render. I can resolve to angular's http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according [Jared Eitnier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133306/jared-eitnier)'s advice, finally I implement as this,
server side,
public function info()

```
{
    $data['var1'] = $var1;
    $data['var2'] = $var2;
    $data['var3'] = $var3;
    ...
    return Response::json($data);
}
```

client side,
$http.get("url")

```
.success(function(response)
{
    $scope.var1 = response.var1;
    $scope.var1 = response.var1;
    $scope.var1 = response.var1;
    ...
});
```

Answer (score -3):

when you start your angular app, use app.value() to store data in app service; then get it by dependency injection.

example:

```
<script>
<?php
    $data = View::make('----', $data)
?>
app.init(<?php echo json_encode($data)?>)
/* 
    app.init = function(phpData){
       app.value('data',phpData);
       app.bootstrap();
    }
*/
/* get data by dependency injection */
app.controller('myController',[$scope,$injector,function($scope,$injector){
    $scope.data = $injector.get('data');

}])
</script>
```

Comment: Please specify code to solve the question. This is more suited as a comment.